# Creating dataframe with missing values

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I am experienced in Polars' Python package and just starting to use the Rust crate.

In a function I want to return a DataFrame that almost certainly has columns with missing values. My current approach is to create vectors with sentinel values as a starting point for a DataFrame and then I hope to replace those values with `null`s.
But I'm not having much success.

I can create the vectors and DataFrame with something like this

```
let mut a_vec: Vec<i64> = Vec::with_capacity(10);

for i in 0..10 {
    if <condition> {
        a_vec[i] = 1;
    } else {
        a_vec[i] = std::i64::MAX
    }
}

let mut df: DataFrame = df!("a" => a_vec).unwrap();
```

Now I want to replace `std::i64::MAX` with `null`.

In Python Polars I can run use the [`replace` method](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.replace.html#polars.Series.replace), but I haven't found a (good) way to this in Rust.

If there is a better way to do this where I can avoid the sentinel values I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to create a vector of `Option`s:

```rust
let mut a_vec: Vec<Option<i64>> = Vec::with_capacity(10);

for i in 0..10 {
    if i != 5 {
        a_vec.push(Some(1));
    } else {
        a_vec.push(None);
    }
}

let mut df: DataFrame = df!("a" => a_vec).unwrap();
```

You can also use chunked array builders, it should be more efficient:

```rust
let mut a_vec: PrimitiveChunkedBuilder<Int64Type> = PrimitiveChunkedBuilder::new("a", 10);

for i in 0..10 {
    if i != 5 {
        a_vec.append_value(1);
    } else {
        a_vec.append_null();
    }
}

let a_vec = a_vec.finish();

let mut df: DataFrame = df!("a" => a_vec).unwrap();
```